# Editing static resources in Docker with Spring Boot application

Tags: docker, spring-boot

I am creating an application with Spring Boot and Docker.  What I want to do is edit the static resources (.js and .css) without having to stop/rebuild/start the container.

I have read a few tutorials, blogs, and examples (including http://bsideup.blogspot.com/2015/04/spring-boots-fat-jars-vs-docker.html) Every example I have seen looks like I must rebuild the jar, rebuild the container, and stop/start the container to see any sort of change.

Have I overlooked some configuration that would allow me to edit a .css file and immediately see the change reflected in the browser?

Comment: That is the way docker is supposed to be used.

Comment: If I change a style setting (e.g. change a background color) the intended docker use case is to wait 30 seconds to be able to see this change?  I am currently using docker to run a tomcat instance where my local changes are shared with docker (and instantly available) so I know it can be done, but I have not found a way to make it work with Spring Boot.

Comment: Well doable yes. But usually you go for docker to be able to ship your environment rather easily and spin up new instances when needed. For sure you can also share this. In this case I'd suggest you build a docker image that uses a folder of another docker container which then could be shared. See "Creating and mounting a data Volume container" (https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/). In these cases be sure not to compile you spring-boot app to a runnable jar but start it using mvn spring-boot:run.